# Added validation but the input data is not entered Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, validation

I added validation in Controller but the data is not entered, it just returns to the form page. before i add validation all good. then I added the obligation to each input also went well, it only displays an error code because the data is empty,
when i add message via

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
    if ($validator->fails ()) {
return redirect()-> back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput ($ request-> all ());
```

goes well to display message data is still empty,
after submit, the data does not enter the database, but only returns to the form page

Controller:

```
 public function pushQordh(Request $request)
{
    $rules=[
        'tglangsur'=>'required',
        'data_qordh'=>'required',
        'jumlah'=>'required',
        'keterangan'=>'required'
    ];
    $messages = [
        'tglangsur.required' => 'Tanggal harus diisi !!!',
        'data_qordh.required'=> 'Data qordh tidak boleh kosong !!!',
        'jumlah.required'    => 'Jumlah harus diisi dengan angka !!!'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all());
    } 
        $qordh = new AngsuranQordh();
        $qordh->no_anggota = $request->id_anggota;
        $qordh->tgl = $request->tglangsur;
        $qordh->data_akad = $request->data_akad;
        $qordh->jumlah = $request->jumlah;
        $qordh->keterangan = $request->keterangan;
        $qordh->save();
        return redirect('/angsuran/qordh')->with('status','Data berhasil ditambahkan');
}
```

View:

```
<form action="/angsuran/qordh/tambah" method="post">
  <!--card-body -->
  @csrf
    <div class="card-body col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_anggota">No. Anggota</label>
        <input type="id" class="form-control col-md-4" name="id_anggota" value="{{$detailAnggota->id_anggota}}" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nama</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control col-md-6" id="name" value="{{$detailAnggota->name}}" readonly>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tglangsur">Tanggal</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control col-sm-4" name="tglangsur" placeholder="Tanggal" value="{{old('tglangsur')}}">
        @if ($errors->has('tglangsur'))
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('tglangsur') }}</span>
        @endif
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Data Qordh</label>
        @if ($detailQordh == null)
           <div class="alert alert-danger">
            Data qordh tidak ditemukan
           </div>
        @else
           <select type="text" class="form-control" name="data_akad">
            <option>{{$detailAnggota->name}} | {{$detailQordh->tgl}} | Rp. @currency($detailQordh->jumlah)</option>
           </select>
        @endif
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="jumlah">Jumlah</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="jumlah" placeholder="Jumlah" value="{{old('jumlah')}}">
        @if ($errors->has('jumlah'))
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('jumlah') }}</span>
        @endif
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Keterangan</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="keterangan" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 131px;">Oke...</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="card-footer">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `old()` method, it give you access to old value of input, check more in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old)

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="login" value="{{old('login')}}">
```

Comment: I have entered it, the problem is that the data is not entered

Comment: I didn't see the input with name "data_qordh" in your html, but in the rules you say that it is "required"

Comment: Oh ya...
apparently that was the error
I am not careful in making code :D
Thank you very much